# Curly brackets are appearing along with the variable name when I try to echo on laraval

Tags: laravel

When I try to echo and display the output of a query in my dashboard it is appearing like this

`[{"job_type":"Sales Manager"}]`

The query is this:

```
        ->where('id',$userId)
        ->select('job_type')
        ->get();
```

To display it on the dashboard I am using this code

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xlg-3">
                <div class="card card-hover">
                    <div class="box bg-cyan text-center">
                        <h1 class="font-light text-white"><i class="mdi mdi-view-dashboard"></i></h1>
                        <h5 class="m-b-0 m-t-5 text-white">{{ $jobType }}</h5>
                        <h6 class="text-white">Designation</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How do I just get the result instead of the variable name along with the brackets?

Comment: Your question is a little bit ambiguous for me, can you explain what you actually want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query

```
->where('id',$userId)
    ->pluck('job_type')
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should print it like `{{$jobType->job_type}} or {{$jobType['job_type']}}` based on your return type.

Answer (score 0):

```
->where('id',$userId)
->select('job_type')
->get();
```

This code will return Collection instance so you should either use first(); or you iterate over the variable. You probably try to get the user so you should use it like this:

```
 $user = User::where('id', $userId)->first();
```

and use below code in your view

```
{{ $user->job_type }}
```

Or you can use

```
$user = User::find($userId);
```